# Does leaving LTE on when LTE service is unavailable drain the battery faster?

Tags: iphone

The iPhone 5-series phones all support LTE but if I only have a contract for 3G service will my iPhone battery drain faster because it's always trying to find an an LTE-capable signal? Can I stop it from even looking for LTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the LTE on will not drain your battery life. The data modem in your phone (a Qualcomm MDM9615M) is a chip that handles LTE and 3G signals. Therefore, your phone is not using a 3G chip and then draining your battery by having a second chip search for a LTE signal.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not specifically what you're asking, but you can disable LTE in settings.

Settings > Cellular > Enable LTE (switch to off)

[image: LTE Setting]

Comment: great thank you, i don't have iPhone 5 but ur answer is ok

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - This is not the case.  Apple put the switch there, in my opinion, to allow you to disable LTE when you're in an area with low LTE signal.  It doesn't kill the data connection, or even non-edge data connection, completely.  I've edited my answer to include an updated screenshot.

Comment: Corroborating @MrRabbit's answer: disabling LTE *does not* disable wireless data services. 4G and 3G are still available.

Comment: @Kiti if this answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted by pressing the green checkmark button just below the down vote button. For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).